# Enable both hardware and soft keyboard android tablet

Tags: android

I am using barcode scanner for an application. I want soft keyboard be enabled after I connect my barcode reader device. I am using this view where barcode should be read in Fragment.

I am also facing issue that app is getting restarted once we connect hardware device.

Comment: Code?????? error exception something to work with

Comment: I am not writing any specific code just forcefully trying to display soft keyboard when Barcode Scanner is connected. I am new in hardware implementation and checked many links but not finding exact solution.

Comment: I am using Honeywell barcode scanner to read barcode. Now once we connect the soft keyboard is going on. I want both to be enable since we have to enter some values and update back for that particular product in db..

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        if (keyCode == 61) {
            if (barCode.length() < 5) {
                barCode = "";
                return false;
            }
           
            barCode = "";
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode != 59) {
            barCode += ((char) event.getUnicodeChar());

            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: This is code I am using to get barcode by connecting scanner. But I need soft keyboard also to be visible so that password can be enter or able to edit inventory.